# Finding frequency of user per value in other column

Tags: r

newbie coder here. So let's say I have a df like below. I wanted to be able to say what the most frequent "user" is for each "Name". I'd like to be able to say, "aaa" is the most frequent user for "Alex", and "ddd" is the most frequent user for "Bob". Example origin df below:

```
USER    TITLE   NAME
aaa        1    Alex
aaa        2    Alex
aaa        3    Alex
aaa        4    Alex
aaa        5    Alex
bbb        6    Alex
bbb        7    Alex
ddd        8    Alex
aaa        1    Bob
aaa        2    Bob
bbb        3    Bob
bbb        4    Bob
bbb        5    Bob
ddd        6    Bob
ddd        7    Bob
ddd        8    Bob
ddd        9    Bob
```

I'd then like the results to look like this:

```
NAME    USER (most frequent)  USER (2nd frequent)
Alex    aaa                   bbb
Bob     ddd                   bbb
```

Maybe it's late at night, but I can't refer to any code I've written previously that can sort data in this way.

Do I need to subset each value that occurs in NAME and then just table() the USERs?

If it helps, USER is static, with only 5 or 6 "users" in the column (aaa to eee, let's say). As a bonus, perhaps I can have a third column with the 2nd most frequent user? Help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

One way using `data.table` would be get the nrows  (`.N`) by group ('USER', 'NAME'), `order` the 'N', select the first two rows (`.SD[1:2]`), by 'NAME', create sequence variable ('ind') by 'NAME' and `dcast` from 'long' to 'wide' format.

```
library(data.table)
 dcast(setDT(df1)[,list(N=.N), .(USER, NAME)][order(-N),.SD[1:2] ,
       NAME][, ind:= paste0('USER', 1:.N), NAME], NAME~ind, value.var='USER')
 #    NAME USER1 USER2
 #1: Alex   aaa   bbb
 #2:  Bob   ddd   bbb
```

NOTE: We can change the column names to 'USER FREQUENT1', 'USER FREQUENT2' etc by changing in the `paste0` or can use `setnames`on the output.

Or using `base R`, we can get the `table` of 'NAME', 'USER', columns, `order` the dataset ('d1'), create a sequence column ('ind') for the grouping variable 'NAME', `subset`, and use `reshape` to change the format from 'long' to 'wide'.

```
 d1 <- as.data.frame(table(df1[c(3,1)]))
 d2 <- d1[with(d1, order(NAME, -Freq)),]
 d2$ind <- with(d2, ave(Freq, NAME, FUN=seq_along))
 reshape(subset(d2, ind <3, -Freq), idvar='NAME', 
            timevar='ind', direction='wide')
 #  NAME USER.1 USER.2
 #1 Alex    aaa    bbb
 #6  Bob    ddd    bbb
```

#### data

```
 df1 <- structure(list(USER = c("aaa", "aaa", "aaa", "aaa", "aaa", 
 "bbb", 
 "bbb", "ddd", "aaa", "aaa", "bbb", "bbb", "bbb", "ddd", "ddd", 
 "ddd", "ddd"), TITLE = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 
 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L), NAME = c("Alex", "Alex", "Alex", 
 "Alex", "Alex", "Alex", "Alex", "Alex", "Bob", "Bob", "Bob", 
 "Bob", "Bob", "Bob", "Bob", "Bob", "Bob")), .Names = c("USER", 
 "TITLE", "NAME"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -17L))
```